# Given three linearly independent vectors $(X,Y,Z$), create a vector $A,$ which has the same angle towards $X,Y,Z.$

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, independence

As the title suggests, I'm supposed to find a vector A in $\mathbb R^3$ that has the same angle towards the three vectors **X**,**Y**,**Z**. I've been given a hint to solve the equation **A**=a**X**+b**Y**+c**Z** for the unknown variables a,b and c. I understand why I should solve this equation system, but that will only leave me with more unknown variables than equations. How am I supposed to solve this when there isn't enough information provided?

Thank you taking your time!

Comment: I don't have an answer, but I might start with a specific, computationally easy case to try to see what's going on. For example, start with the standard basis vectors $(1,0,0), (0,1,0), (0,0,1)$ and see if you can find a vector $A$ that works. Maybe there are multiple possible answers, which might be why you can't simply solve for a unique solution. Then try to generalize ...

Comment: Here's a better hint. First make the $3$ given vectors into unit vectors in the same directions. Then you want $A.X = A.Y = A.Z$ (dot products, sorry I don't know how to format much). That is, $A.(X-Y) = A.(Y - Z) = 0$. Thus $A$ is orthogonal to both $(X - Y)$ and $(Y - Z)$. Can you finish it from there ...

Comment: @Ned I see what you mean now. But are there any special rules that apply to **A** since it now is orthogonal to two vectors?

Comment: Because right now, I'm stuck with a couple of equations that seem to cancel each other out...

Comment: Are you familiar with the cross product of 3-dimensional vectors?

Comment: Yes, I am! I do know some cross product rules.

Comment: My last comment: Do you know the geometric relationship between $V x W$ and the vectors $V$ and $W$?

Comment: I think so. The cross product is a vector orthogonal to the vectors in the cross product-

Comment: So ... you want a vector which is orthogonal to both $(X-Y)$ and $(Y-Z)$. One way find such vector is to compute ... what?

Comment: Oh, now I think I understand it better. I can use the cross product to construct the vector A. Thank you so much for the tip! EDIT: I think I've understood everything now, thanks to you!

Comment: Glad to help, have fun.